# Closing form in access automatically updates first row in table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am working on a simple database in MS Access for small manufacturer. Its very simple and small.

Basically I have a form where workers can log what they did during the day. I have 4 Combo boxes and 3 text boxes.

Every think works like a charm until I close the form. When I close it, it updates first row, but it only changes what was in text boxes, data form combo boxes is the same. E.g. worker enters some data, clicks insert and table is updated with this new information. Then when he/she clicks close this information is inserted in first row in this table, but changes only what was in text boxes. 
Same think happens no matter what, if there is data in those boxes or not.

This is how I close my form:

```
Public Sub Close (formMe As Form)
    DoCmd.Close acForm, formMe.Name
    DoCmd.OpenForm "WorkerLogin"
End Sub
```

But I noticed that same think occurs if I ran the form as pop up, and then closing it with X.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: Does it ever work? Under what conditions does it work? If you move to another record rather than closing the form, does it work? What is bound to the combo boxes? What is bound to the text boxes?

Comment: I fixed it with Me.Unload, before closing

Answer (score 1):

I manage to fixed it with

```
Me.Unload
```

before closing it.